# for-Loop to add integers

Tags: c++, for-loop

Here are the instructions:

---

Write a program that accepts an integer input from the keyboard and computes the sum of all the integers from 1 to that integer. Example, if 7 were input, the sum: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 would be computed. Use a while or for loop to perform the calculations. Print out the result after the sum has been calculated. NOTE: if you input a large integer, you will not get the correct results.

---

**What I can't figure out is how to ADD all of the integers together**. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//preprocessor directives


int main ()
{
//declare and initialize variables

    int n, i;
    int total;


//user input

    cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    cin >> n;


//compute sum of all integers from 1 to n
    total=0;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    cout << i;


return 0;
}
```

Comment: so you learned how to do input with `cin >> n;` but didn't learn how to use `+` yet? seems unlikely O.o

Comment: you could also point out that a four loop is not required as the result is `n * (n + 1) / 2`.

Comment: @EdHeal, Okay! Let's see, 50000 * 50001 / 2 = ... DANG IT

Comment: you may want to use `atoi` for that `cin` input http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi . http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0100__Development/cinandatoiatoffunctions.htm

Comment: @user2485710 - Why? `if (cin >> n) { do summat}else{ report error}`

Comment: @user2485710 shouldn't need to, it is being put into an int. It should convert just fine. Should probably check that an actual integer is input though.

Comment: @user3754573 I think what he is trying to point out is that you managed to figure out how to use `cin` but you couldnt figure out how to use `+=`, perhaps you should have considered doing a little more research before you asked on this site.

Comment: @ben - I agreee - Also doing some research you might learn other stuff along the way (like the joys of division)

Comment: I am reading 3 books . . . on my own. I am doing plenty of research. My teacher skips over important points in order to teach more in the short time. I'm not the only one with these problems. MY point is that this is a site to ask for help. If you don't want to help, then why respond in the first place? Move on.

Comment: @user3754573 _' My teacher skips over important points in order to teach more in the short time.'_ Choose another teacher/course then! Blame him at your school's advisory board!

Comment: @user3754573 No kidding. My work is paying for this class, so it's not a simple matter of dropping the class. I'm doing the best I can. I already have an M.S. (not in computer science, obviously), so I am far from stupid. I'm just not familiar with programming AT ALL, which is why I am taking the class. But again, is this site not for help? Or is it for arrogant geeks to make fun of those of us who are trying to learn?

Comment: I would stick with reading one book at a time. Use the other two for reference. BTW - How can skipping bits mean you learn quicker?

Comment: @EdHeal: That is the problem. This is a beginning class but the teacher acts as if we already know programming. We will hand in assignments and THEN he proceeds to tell us that he forgot to go over something that would have helped :S

Comment: @user3754573 StackOverflow is a Q&A site for __professional and enthusiast programmers__. Not just for "asking for help". It's not our duty to solve every problem you have, we can however do it - if we find the question interesting. Your duty however - before asking - is to ensure you did everything to solve the problem yourself. Did you? I mean - searching the Internet for _"adding numbers C++"_ yelds hundreds of results. Moreover - you're the one considered arrogant here because of the overreacting to a comment. Maybe calm down a bit.

Comment: @user3754573 - Just read one book. Assignments are there to study. That is something else to learn as well as to how to find out stuff

Comment: @PawełStawarz BAM, debater of the month! Except that it yields 7,370,000 results!

Comment: @Ben googling _""adding numbers C++""_ yields __9__ (!) results for me :( Googling _"adding numbers C++"_ yelds 29`600`000 tho. So one would probably preffer the first, since the latter gives too much information at once (_snrk_).

Comment: @PawelStawarz cant argue with you! You are too good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add by using the `+=` operator:

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    total += i;
cout << total;
```

Note this is short for `total = total + i`.

Comment: Thank you for your actual help and kindness.

Comment: @user3754573 Anytime :)